# putting binary numbers converted with bitset in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary, bitset

I'm making a program that converts bytes from a string into a binary system and then store them into a vector. I need to use bitset to convert them. My question is: how can i store the results in a vector b? I thought about saving them one number by one number, but how the loop would look like?

```
string key = "codekeys";
char text;
vector<int> k;
vector<int> b;

void f() {
    for(char& text : key) {
        k.push_back(text);
    }
    cout << "k size: " << k.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<k.size(); i++) {
        cout << k[i] << " in binary " << bitset<8> (k[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make b a vector of bitsets then you can store them easily.

```
string key = "codekeys";
char text;
vector<int> k;
vector<bitset<8>> b;

void f() {
    for(char& text : key) {
        k.push_back(text);
        b.push_back(bitset<8>(text)); // convert to bitset and store in b
    }
    cout << "k size: " << k.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<k.size(); i++) {
        cout << k[i] << " in binary " << b[i] << endl; // print b
    }

}
```